# Facebook app notification template with user id ( @[user_id] ) not working

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl, facebook-app-requests

I can't get the @[user_id] template to work using:

```
$userid = <USER_ID>;
$friendId = <FRIEND_ID>; // This is a user who has accepted the app
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/$userid/notifications";
$attachment =  array(   
                 'access_token'  => "$app_token",
                 'href' =>  "",
                 'template' => "@[" . $friendId . "] accepted challenge!"
               );
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attachment);
//curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

`$result` returns 'false'

`$friendId` is a valid app user and
`$app_token` is "appid|appsecret"

If I replace 'template' with a simple message such as "test" it all works fine

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably using a wrong user ID. In order to make sure you're using the appropriate ID for your friend, use me/friends with a valid user access token for your App and check if the ID is in the list and if it's a normal user id or an app scoped ID.

Please also make sure your App is not in "Developer Mode", if so, you will need to add your user as tester or developer so you can test your App.

I've tested this a couple of minutes ago and it works well.

As a unrelated question, wouldn't be easier use Facebook's PHP SDK?

I hope it helps.

---

**Edit: App Scoped User ID**

Facebook introduced versioning in April 2014. In Facebook API V2, we introduced the App Scoped User ID, you can read more about it here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids

Basically, if your FB App was created after April 2014, you'll receive a unique ID for each user that can be used only by your App. You must to use this new App Scoped User ID instead of the normal Facebook User ID.

Comment: Thanks. I checked all of this but still no joy. My app is in developer mode but the friend in question is marked as a tester. One thing I didn't understand though - what is an app scoped ID? Should the template include the regular user ID or an app scoped user ID?

Comment: Hi techsMex, I've updated my answer with a brief explanation and a link to the App scoped ID. The best way to check if your friend has a normal user ID or an App Scoped ID is calling to me/friends and use the ID provided there.

Comment: Also, please note that Facebook API will always return an error code and error description instead of just "false" when the API call fails. Your PHP code is probably not handling the error response correctly. I would recommend to use Facebook Graph API Explorer (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) to test your API call and see the real error. It should be clear enough to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, my app was originally created in 2010 but that is good to know! I'll try php sdk and get some more info